# onAuthStateChanged is not invoked and user remains null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My code where I want to read the data:

```
public class DonorDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference donorDatabase;
private String TAG = "DonorDetails";
private FirebaseUser user;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_donor_details);

    //initializing Firebase Database Object
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:281410145157:android:6a1794e09956e306") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("AIzaSyB5MaQmmwSqgeVS9htvbVSMPizmuARkzYU") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://e-blood-f1d0c.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();
    FirebaseApp donorApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "DonorDetails");
    donorDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(donorApp).getReference();


    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };

    // Read from the database
    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            Donor value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Donor.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
}
```

Code to create new user:

```
public class UserRegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private static final String TAG = "Registration";
private EditText emailEditText, passwordEditText, nameEditText, phoneEditText, ageEditText, addressEditText, occupationEditText;
private Spinner bloodgroupSpinner;
private DatabaseReference donorDatabase;
private String userBloodGroup;
FirebaseUser user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_registration);

    //initializing Firebase Authentication Object
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //initializing Firebase Database Object
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:281410145157:android:6a1794e09956e306") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("AIzaSyB5MaQmmwSqgeVS9htvbVSMPizmuARkzYU") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://e-blood-f1d0c.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();
    FirebaseApp donorApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "DonorRegistration");
    donorDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(donorApp).getReference();

    //initializing Views
    emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text);
    nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
    phoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_edit_text);
    ageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age_edit_text);
    addressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address_edit_text);
    occupationEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.occupation_edit_text);
    bloodgroupSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.blood_group_spinner);
    View registerButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.register_button);

    //ArrayAdapter for the Blood Group Spinner
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.blood_group, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bloodgroupSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    bloodgroupSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            userBloodGroup = bloodgroupSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Bloood group is: " + userBloodGroup, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    //Authentication Listener
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };

    //Register On-Click
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}

//RegisterUser
private void registerUser() {
    String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(UserRegistrationActivity.this, "You are not eligible. Sorry",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        writeNewDonor(task.getResult().getUser());
                        Intent userDetails = new Intent(UserRegistrationActivity.this, DonorDetails.class);
                        startActivity(userDetails);
                    }
                }
            });
}

//Add Details to Database
private void writeNewDonor(FirebaseUser user) {
    String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
    long phone = Long.parseLong(phoneEditText.getText().toString());
    int age = Integer.parseInt(ageEditText.getText().toString());
    String address = addressEditText.getText().toString();
    String bloodGroup = userBloodGroup;
    String occupation = occupationEditText.getText().toString();

    Donor donor = new Donor(name, phone, age, address, bloodGroup, occupation);

    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()).child("Name").setValue(donor.getName());
    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()).child("Phone").setValue(donor.getPhone());
    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()).child("Age").setValue(donor.getAge());
    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()).child("Address").setValue(donor.getAddress());
    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()).child("BloodGroup").setValue(donor.getBloodGroup());
    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()).child("Occupation").setValue(donor.getOccupation());
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
}
```

Int the code to read data the onAuthStateChanged is not getting invoked and the user is not getting initialized.
The error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Comment: Little tips, next time you should post only lines of code that you know is related to the problem, because question that include the whole code will make us more likely to pass without even trying to help you. **Aside from that**, on which line does the exception occurs? is it when create new user or read data

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. This happens when you read the data. I want to access the user.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by `user` object is null when this code runs:

```
donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid()) ...
```

I'm not really understand the flow of your code, but you can avoid this error by making sure `user` object is filled first before getting uid from it, like this:

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    donorDatabase.child("Donors").child(user.getUid())
}
```

Hope this helps.